# how to send one transaction from multiples seed wallets?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, hd-wallets

I would like to know if there is posible to group 3 wallet balances derived from a seed phrase and send one tx.

Example :

The user received 1 ETH to address A, 1 ETH on address B, ETH on address C.

Now the user wants to send 3 ETH to another wallet. How would he do it? What about miner fee, will be multiples transactions, one transaction?

there is an code example of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no it's not possible. A transaction can only have one sender which is the private key used to sign it. You'll have to send all ETH to the same address first, so in total 3 transactions.